# using bootstrap-datepicker with angularjs. Need to find a way to update ng-model when a date is chosen

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ngmodel, bootstrap-datepicker

In short, I need to find a way to update ng-model when using bootstrap-datepicker. Here is a plunker I made to demonstrate what is going on http://plnkr.co/edit/nNTEM25I2xX2zRKOWbD1?p=preview. I've tried searching around and am fairly positive that I need to use a directive to pass a value to the model. Typing something in the text box will update the selected date model, but just using the datepicker does nothing. The below directive seemed like it should work but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have much of an effect.

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function() {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',

                    onSelect : function(date) {

                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);

                        element.datepicker("setDate", date);

                        scope.$apply();

                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

An easy solution would be to just use another datepicker, but unfortunately due to restrictions on how many external libraries I can use this is the datepicker I have to use. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you looked at UI-Bootstrap? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: That is what I was originally using, but the style of the calendar did not fit with our website and it was causing a few issues with in-line editing so we scrapped it and are trying to use the datepicker that comes with the theme we are using to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend using UI-Bootstrap or something similar.

But for those that need to use Bootstraps date-picker for whatever reason here is a starting place using your directive, with a few changes:

```
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      compile: function() {
         return {
            pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
               // Initialize the date-picker
               $(element).datepicker({
                  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
               }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                  // Binds the changes back to the controller
                  // I also found that event.format() returns the string
                  // I wasn't aware of that. Sure beats using the date object and formatting yourself.
                  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ev.format('dd/mm/yyyy'));

                  // I HATE using $apply, but I couldn't get it to work without
                  scope.$apply();
               });
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" datepicker="" ng-model="date" />
```

Very simple and straightforward and allows you to reuse, <kbd>[here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJiDJc1umtnR5veflaOP?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Argh, this seems so simple and looks like it should work but I can't get it to work in the plunker I have for whatever reason. I'm probably doing something silly.

Comment: Hmm, well for some reason I can't get your plunker to even open right now. I'll keep trying and take a look at it and let you know if there is anything I see.

Comment: Hmmmm, well, for some reason it seems that you need to use the top datepicker before the bottom one works. I stripped the actual page I'm working on to get it looking nice for a plunker, but all of the bsic functionality is there.

Comment: The only thing I see is that you are missing `class='date-picker'` so the document on ready isn't called on the second date selector. I added that and it worked fine onload

Comment: @JDubs Got it working in your directive, [Here's my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fJiDJc1umtnR5veflaOP?p=preview), Let me know what you think. I will change my answer to reflect this in a few minutes.

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you so much! It's so simple haha. I don't know why I didn't catch that I needed to have my "on" event handler inside the directive itself. Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Not a problem, best of luck. I am going to have to steal this for myself as well. The way I originally did it was when I was first learning AngularJS and JQuery, this is a MUCH more elegant solution.